# "Database is locked" error in SQLite3 with Qt

Tags: multithreading, qt, sqlite

I'm using SQLite3 on an embedded system and on x86 in a Qt application. I'm experiencing the common error "Database is locked" when multiple threads try to read/write the database.

I read [this](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=DatabaseIsLocked) article suggested in some other answers, but I'm creating a different connection for each thread.

By adjusting a bit the QSQLITE_BUSY_TIMEOUT option (to a very large value: 10000000) I solved this problem on the x86 system and on the embedded system, but in the latter case only when not using transactions. Unfortunately I need to use transactions for all the work of each thread.

My question is: isn't it supported by SQLite3 to read/write from/to the database concurrently when using transactions? Why doesn't it simply wait all the necessary time to acquire the lock? Maybe I haven't set it up correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [BEGIN TRANSACTION](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) statement of SQL. It explicitly says that the default transaction behavior is deferred which explains the error that you are seeing. Also read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943398/why-does-sqlite-give-a-database-is-locked-for-a-second-query-in-a-transaction-w) for another good explanation.

So you need to start your SQL as "BEGIN **IMMEDIATE** TRANSACTION"and everybody else must do the same.

You can find source code example [here](http://gitorious.org/semperfosdem/semperfosdem/blobs/b47e36d7d2550417126c0b8424daf254abc0c2f8/src/sql/sqlengine.cpp). Pay attention to

```
bool SqlEngine::beginTransaction()
```

method and do the same in your code.

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to understand why this is working and DEFERRED was not OK, but the documentation you provided is very clear so I'll get it sooner or later :-) Anyway, it is working now. Thanks!