# Qt multithreaded transactions in SQLite

Tags: qt, sqlite, transactions, qsqldatabase

How can one get access to transactions using [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/docs.html) through [QSqlDatabase](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html) ?

I open the database as follows:

```
m_db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", connection_name);
m_db.setDatabaseName(db_name);
m_db.open();
```

I create two such connections - for my Read and Write threads.
The problem is that I have a large data stream to write, therefore I have to use begin and commit transactions at least in the Write thread. 
Write thread works well, but I cannot make any select request until Write thread closed its connection.
Here is how I use transactions:

```
m_db.transaction(); // BEGIN TRANSACTION

// Many QSqlRequest-s like so:
QString insert = "INSERT INTO mytable (x, y, z) VALUES (:x, :y, :z);"
QSqlQuery query(m_db);
bool ok = query.prepare(insert);
if (ok)
{
    query.addBindValue(x);
    query.addBindValue(y);
    query.addBindValue(z);
    //...
    if (query.exec())
    {
        // ok
    }
    else
    {
        // show error
    }
}
else
{
    // show error
}

m_db.commit(); // COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

This is a common using.
The problem is these standard operations don't support multithreading using. **How can I get access to normal multithreading transactions?** QSqlDatabase supports threads by default, and I can read/write in both threads without transactions, but transactions are necessary.
How can I setup all usual multithreading options using QSqlDatabase and SQLite?

I can invoke `q.exec("BEGIN IMMEDIATE  TRANSACTION");` , but it returns error while using in both threads:  `database is locked Unable to fetch row`.

Links:
["Database is locked" error in SQLite3 with Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369677/database-is-locked-error-in-sqlite3-with-qt)
[Why does SQLite give a "database is locked" for a second query in a transaction when using Perl's DBD::SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943398/why-does-sqlite-give-a-database-is-locked-for-a-second-query-in-a-transaction)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5). SQLite does not have much concurrency support.

To allow one writer and readers at the same time, use [WAL mode](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html).

Comment: Do you know hot to enter WAL Mode with QSqlDatabase ?

Comment: @Kingsley The linked page shows what SQL command to execute.